# Karate - callonce feature doesn't cache the response

Tags: karate

I have two feature files and I'm trying to reuse the result of the first feature file as a background to the second feature file's scenario

Feature file 1

`Feature: First feature file
  Scenario: create random session id
    * def sessionId = Java.type('com.company.RandomSessionId').getRandomSessionId()`

Feature file 2

`Feature: calling another feature file
  Background:
    * def mycall = callonce read('first.feature')
    * def randomId = mycall.sessionId`

Scenario: print sessionId
    * print randomId
  Scenario: print sessionId-2
    * print randomId

When I execute the scenarios in Feature file 2, I get two different results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It must be because you are using the IDE support / right-click / "run-as" option. This is an open issue, because Karate needs to cache across Scenarios which "native" Cucumber does not support: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/136 - apologies and I need to update the documentation.

Please use a JUnit runner for these cases, I recommend having these in place for dev-mode anyway, and the new HTML dev-mode report makes this even more useful: https://twitter.com/KarateDSL/status/935029435140489216